# Script for redirect to member's page after logging in

Tags: php, redirect, authentication

I just want to now the script for redirecting after logging in on my webpage and the script that i put on all the webpages on my website for redirecting to member's page if you are already logged in, like in Facebook if i refresh the page I am still connected.

Answer (score 0):

There are a hundred ways of doing it, but you can start by setting a session value right after a successful login attempt, such as:

```
$_SESSION["loggedin"] = true;
```

Now in your member pages you can check if the user is authenticated like so:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION["loggedin"]))
{
    //redirect user to login form
}

//Member page
```

In the example above, if the user is not logged in, you must redirect him to the login form.

Every place in your app where you desire to use `$_SESSION`, you must have `session_start();` at the beginning of your script. If you don't have, it won't work.